Access page specific javascript in rails 7.2
I am using importmap-rails.
I have a common.js file at app/javascript/controllers/center/staff_profiles/common.js
in importmap, i already pinned controllers using below
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
In index.html, I am calling common.js like below
<%= content_for :page_specific_scripts do %>
  <%=  javascript_import_module_tag 'controllers/center/staff_profiles/common' %>
<% end %>

I have page_specific_scripts in layouts
Everything is working as expected till this place.
I have another file app/javascript/controllers/shared/scroll.js like below
export function handleScroll(){
--  scroll code
}

and i am calling this in another js file app/javascript/controllers/user/work.js like below
import {handleScroll} from "../../shared/scroll";

document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function() {
    handleScroll();
});

Then I got error in production which says https://myapp.com/assets/controllers/shared/scroll” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
This is working in local env.
I am using Rails 7.2

The problem is the behaviour of how i am importing javascript file in other file. Need the complete path instead of relative path
I changed from
import {handleScroll} from "../../shared/scroll";

to
import {handleScroll} from "controllers/shared/scroll";

Inside importmap.rb, I have pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
So, on production environment
it will map
controllers/shared/scroll
to
controllers/shared/scroll-hash-fingerprint2312312dsfsdfsdss.js
